# NodeJS behavior when reading a file when all threads from the pool are busy

Tags: node.js, multithreading, node.js-fs

I started learning Node.JS and ran into several misunderstandings that I couldn't find answers online.
Let's say I use non-blocking file reading

```
fs.readFile("filename.txt", (err, data) => {
    ...
})
```

As far as I know, reading a file is a synchronous operation performed by a thread (if you do not use third-party libraries, but I could be wrong). This is how I understand what happens next:
one of the free threads from the pool will “take” this task => after completion, a callback will be executed.
So I have a few questions:

1. What happens if all threads are busy with other tasks when I want to read a file? Will the main thread wait until one of the threads is free to give it this task?
2. If so, is it normal practice to create a Worker Thread in such situations?

Comment: Javascript is single threaded by nature. There is no concept of threads as far as the language is concerned. A better mental model is a queue of code-blocks.

Comment: @super - This is not true.  Nodejs uses a thread pool internal to its implementation and that's part of what the OP is asking about.  And, separately, there is also [WorkerThread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) which allows you to create your own Javascript threads in nodejs.

Comment: @jfriend00 What the language does internally is not very relevant. What is relevant is the guarantees the language gives you. Saying there is a thread pool internally makes no difference what so ever to how you should write code or how you should expect it to behave. Going on to explain how this internal thread pool operates gives even less usefull information, especially since you most likely are making assumptions about it. Does it work exactly the same on all OS and all runtimes to start with? No. But that doesn't matter. It's the language guarantees that matter. Not the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within nodejs, file asynchronous operations are carried out by a thread pool.  So, a `fs.readFile()` operation works like this:

1. Call `fs.open()` to open the file in question.
2. The implementation of that calls some native code (built into nodejs).  That native code then asks for an available thread in the thread pool.
3. If a thread is available, the file open operation is turned over to the thread and the open function returns.  This eventually gets control back to the event loop so other nodejs code can run while the thread in the thread pool is doing its work.
4. If a thread is not available, then it registers an internal callback to be notified when a thread is available and then the open function returns.  This eventually gets control back to the event loop so other nodejs code can run while the thread in the thread pool is doing its work.
5. When a thread becomes available, the callback is called and it then picks up where step 3 was.
6. When the thread in the thread pool finishes the open operation, it posts a message to the nodejs event queue indicating that the open operation is complete.  When nodejs is done doing other things and it gets to be this events turn, then nodejs executes the callback associated with the original `fs.open()` call that started all this.
7. That callback then carries on the next step in the `fs.readFile()` operation by starting to read data with `fs.read()` which then goes through a very similar process.

> What happens if all threads are busy with other tasks when I want to read a file? Will the main thread wait until one of the threads is free to give it this task?

The main thread will not wait.  This is all non-blocking.  The operation has been started, it just isn't making progress yet through its first `fs.open()` step because a thread pool thread isn't available.  But, that doesn't make it blocking.  `fs.readFile()` still returns immediately and nodejs is free to do other things.  It's just the the non-blocking `fs.open()` step is taking longer.  Steps 4 and 5 above cover the scenario where no thread is immediately available.

> If so, is it normal practice to create a Worker Thread in such situations?

No, it is not and that may not even help because worker threads may even share the same thread pool.  If you really, really, really want to, you can make the thread pool larger by setting an environment variable before you start nodejs.

But, unless your system has a whole bunch of completely separate disks using separate I/O controllers and these requests are all on separate disks, it's generally not useful to attempt to run a whole bunch of disk requests on the same disk at the same time.  That's because internally, the disk can really only do one thing at a time and attempting to do 10 things at once probably just slows everything down causing everything to take longer, particularly with a spinning disk that has to physically move the read/write head around the platter in order to do anything.  Whereas allowing only a few operations to proceed in parallel and making other operations wait their turn is actually more efficient when they are all competing for the same disk.

Comment: I like the last paragraph here. It gives some actual solid advice. Have a +1.